# working ajax - posting variable into another page that execute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following script that executes after a form has been clicked

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('CODE');

    var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
      var $form = $('#payment-form');

      if (response.error) {
        // Show the errors on the form
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response.id;
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        $form.append($('<input type="text" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
        // and re-submit
      }
    };

    jQuery(function($) {
      $('#payment-form').submit(function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);

        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

        Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

        // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
      });
    });


function phpCall() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'paymentEmail.php',
      success: function (response) {//response is value returned from php (for    your example it's "bye bye"
        alert(response);
      }
   });
}
  </script>
```

My problem is that the php paymentEmail.php does not run after the script is done.

My objective is as follow:
once and only this line has been run

```
  $form.append($('<input type="text" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
```

The followings happen:

- The value of stripeToken gets posted to paymentEmail.php
- paymentEmail.php gets executed.

If you're curious, below is how the paymentEmail.php looks like:

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['paid'])){



               $course_price_final = $_POST['course_price_final'];

 $course_token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
                $course_provider = $_POST['course_provider'];
                $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
$course_delivery = $_POST['course_delivery'];

    $order_date = date("Y-m-d");



         $insert_c = "insert into orders (course_title,course_price_final,course_provider,user_email,course_date,course_delivery,order_date,course_token) 
         values ('$crs_title','$course_price_final','$course_provider','$user_email','$course_date1','$course_delivery','$order_date','$course_token')";

        $run_c = mysqli_query($con, $insert_c); 

}
```

Thanks in advance

Update:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('');

    var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
      var $form = $('#payment-form');

      if (response.error) {
        // Show the errors on the form
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response.id;
        var appendedStripeToken = false;
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
$form.append($('<input type="text" name="stripeToken" />').val(token);  
function handleCall() { if (!appendedStripeToken) { appendedStripeToken = true; phpCall(); } }      // and re-submit
      }
    };

function onSubmit() {
    var $form = $('#'+id_from_form);

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('input').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

}

function phpCall() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'paymentEmail.php',
      success: function (response) {//response is value returned from php (for    your example it's "bye bye"
        alert(response);
      }
   });
}
  </script>
```

Update 2:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('CODE');

    var appendedStripeToken = false;

var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
    var $form = $('#payment-form');

    if (response.error) {
        // Show the errors on the form
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response.id;
        handleCall(token);
    }
};

function handleCall(token) { 
    if (!appendedStripeToken) { 
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        $form.append($('<input type="text" name="stripeToken" />').val(token); 
        appendedStripeToken = true; 
        phpCall(); 
    } 
}

function onSubmit() {
    var $form = $('#payment-form'); // TODO: give your html-form-tag an "id" attribute and type this id in this line. IMPORTANT: Don't replace the '#'!

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $('#paymentSubmit').prop('disabled', true); // TODO: give your html-submit-input-tag an "id" attribute

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
}

function phpCall() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'paymentEmail.php',
        success: function (response) { // response is value returned from php (for your example it's "bye bye")
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
  </script>

</head>

<body>



<form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="row row-centered">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">


  <div class="alert alert-danger" id="a_x200" style="display: none;"> <strong>Error!</strong> <span class="payment-errors"></span> </div>
  <span class="payment-success">
  <? $success ?>
  <? $error ?>
  </span>
  <fieldset>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Choose Start Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select name="course_date" class="address form-control" required>
      <option><?php 

      if(isset($_GET['crs_id'])){

      $course_id = $_GET['crs_id'];

      $get_crs = "select * from courses where course_id='$course_id'";
  $run_crs = mysqli_query($con, $get_crs);

 while($row_crs=mysqli_fetch_array($run_crs)){

        $course_date1  = $row_crs['course_date1'];


        echo $course_date1 ;

  }
}
  ?></option>
  <option value=<?php 

      if(isset($_GET['crs_id'])){

      $course_id = $_GET['crs_id'];

      $get_crs = "select * from courses where course_id='$course_id'";
  $run_crs = mysqli_query($con, $get_crs);

 while($row_crs=mysqli_fetch_array($run_crs)){

        $course_provider = $row_crs['course_provider'];

        $course_date2 = $row_crs['course_date2'];

                $course_price = $row_crs['course_price'];
                                $course_title = $row_crs['course_title'];



        $course_priceFinal = $row_crs['course_priceFinal'];
   $dig = explode(".", $row_crs['course_tax']);
    $course_tax = $dig[1];



        echo $course_date2 ;

  }
}
  ?>/>
  </select>
    </div>
  </div>
<input type="hidden" name="course_provider" value="<?php echo $course_provider; ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="course_title" value="<?php echo $course_title; ?>" >

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Course Delivery</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select name="course_delivery" class="address form-control" required>
    <option value="classroom">Classroom</option>
  </select>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Seats</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select name="course_seats" class="address form-control" required>
      <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Form Name -->
  <legend>Billing Details</legend>

  <!-- Street -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Billing Street</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" name="street" placeholder="Street" class="address form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- City -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Billing City</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" class="city form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- State -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Billing Province</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" name="province" maxlength="65" placeholder="Province" class="state form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Postcal Code -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Postal Code</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" name="postal" maxlength="9" placeholder="Postal Code" class="zip form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Country -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Country</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6"> 
      <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country" class="country form-control">
      <div class="country bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" name="country" placeholder="Select Country" data-flags="true" data-filter="true"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Email -->

  <?php 


  $email = $_GET['user_email'];
// Note the (int). This is how you cast a variable.
$coupon = isset($_GET['crs_coupon']) ? (int)$_GET['crs_coupon'] : '';
if(is_int($coupon)){
    $course_priceFinalAll = $course_priceFinal - ($course_priceFinal * ($coupon/100));
    $coupon_deduction = $course_priceFinal * ($coupon/100);

};

  ?>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" name="user_email" value=<?php echo $email; ?> class="email form-control" required>
            <input type="hidden" name="course_title" value=<?php echo $course_title; ?> class="email form-control">
                        <input type="hidden" id="box1"  name="course_price" value=<?php echo $course_priceFinal; ?> class="email form-control">


    </div>
  </div><br>
    <legend>Purchase Details</legend>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Coupon Code</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text"  style="text-align:left; float:left; border:none; width:100px;"  name="name" class="email form-control" placeholder="Coupon Code" value="<?php echo $coupon; ?>%" readonly>

    </div>
  </div>


    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Want to replace the current coupon code?</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text"  name="name" class="email form-control" placeholder="Please enter another coupon code" value="">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" style="color:#FF6400; font-weight:normal;">Tax</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="email form-control"  name="name"style="text-align:left; float:left; border:none; width:100px;" placeholder="Please enter another coupon code" value=" <?php echo $course_tax; ?>%" readonly>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" style="color:#FF6400;font-weight:normal;">Price before Tax</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" style="text-align:left; float:left; border:none; width:100px;" name="course_price_before_tax" class="email form-control"  value=" $<?php echo $course_price; ?>" readonly>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" style="color:#FF6400; font-weight:normal;">Price After Tax</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" style="text-align:left; float:left; border:none; width:100px;" name="course_price_after_tax" class="email form-control"  value=" $<?php echo $course_priceFinal; ?>" readonly>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" style="color:#FF6400; font-weight:normal;">Coupon Deduction</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" style="text-align:left; float:left; border:none; width:100px;" name="course_deduction" class="email form-control"  value=" -$<?php echo $coupon_deduction; ?>" readonly>

    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" style="color:#FF6400"><b>Final Price</b></label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold; float:left; border:none; width:100px;" name="course_price_final" class="email form-control" placeholder="Course Price Final" value="$<?php echo $course_priceFinalAll; ?>" readonly>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Coupon Code-->
<input type="hidden" name="coupon_code" class="email form-control" placeholder="Coupon Code" value=<?php echo $coupon; ?> readonly>

<!-- Price Final -->
  <br>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Card Details</legend>
        <span class="payment-errors"></span>

    <!-- Card Holder Name -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"  for="textinput">Card Holder's Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" name="cardholdername" maxlength="70"  placeholder="Card Holder Name" class="card-holder-name form-control" required>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Card Number -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Card Number</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" id="cardnumber" maxlength="19" data-stripe="number" placeholder="Card Number" class="card-number form-control" required>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-row">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">CVC</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">

        <input type="text" size="4" class="email form-control" data-stripe="cvc" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
 <br>
    <div class="form-row"><br><br>
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Expiration (MM/YYYY)</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
 <div class="form-inline">
          <select name="select2" data-stripe="exp-month" class="card-expiry-month stripe-sensitive required form-control" required>
            <option value="01" selected="selected">01</option>
            <option value="02">02</option>
            <option value="03">03</option>
            <option value="04">04</option>
            <option value="05">05</option>
            <option value="06">06</option>
            <option value="07">07</option>
            <option value="08">08</option>
            <option value="09">09</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
          </select>



        </div>
      <input type="text" size="4" class="email form-control" data-stripe="exp-year" required/>
    </div>
 </div>


  <br>

    <!-- Submit -->
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <center><br>
       <input id="paymentSubmit" class="btn btn-danger"  name="paid"  onClick="onSubmit()" type="submit" value="Pay Now" class="btn btn-success"></button>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

update

[image]

two minor issues:
With the button being disabled after a click, it wont allow to click again if for instance an error is returned as shown above. It should only disable it after the input has been released

```
$form.append($('<input type="text" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
```

php code

```
 <?php


    $course_price_final = $_POST['course_price_final'];
    $course_token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    $course_provider = $_POST['course_provider'];
    $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
    $course_delivery = $_POST['course_delivery'];
    $order_date = date("Y-m-d");
    $insert_c = "insert into orders (course_title,course_price_final,course_provider,user_email,course_date,course_delivery,order_date,course_token) 
             values ('$crs_title','$course_price_final','$course_provider','$user_email','$course_date1','$course_delivery','$order_date','$course_token')";
    $run_c = mysqli_query($con, $insert_c);

    $location = "../paymentConfirmed.php";









header( "Location: $location" );
```

[image]

```
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// This identifies your website in the createToken call below
Stripe.setPublishableKey('');
var appendedStripeToken = false;

var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
    var $form = $('#payment-form');

    if (response.error) {
        // Show the errors on the form
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response.id;
        handleCall(token);
    }
};

function handleCall(token) { 
    if (!appendedStripeToken) { 
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        $form.append($('<input type="text" name="stripeToken" />').val(token); 
        appendedStripeToken = true; 
        phpCall(); 
    } 
}

function onSubmit() {
    var $form = $('#[put the form id here]'); // TODO: give your html-form-tag an "id" attribute and type this id in this line. IMPORTANT: Don't replace the '#'!

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
}

function phpCall() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'paymentEmail.php',
        success: function (response) { // response is value returned from php (for your example it's "bye bye")
            // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
            $('#[put the input id here]').prop('disabled', true); // TODO: give your html-submit-input-tag an "id" attribute

            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

There are two `TODO` comments!

EDIT: Modified code

Comment: Thank you vm for your help and for stick along. I appreciate the update, you made, but unfortunatetly my problem persist and I think to help you it would be easier if i posted most of the page code. Hence kindly take a look at my update 2 under my initial post. agian thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem. Does the code throw an error? If yes, on which line?

Comment: add this, `var $form = $('#payment-form');` at the first line of the if-block in the `handleCall(...)`-method

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;  $form.append($('<input type="text" name="stripeToken" />').val(token);

Comment: I think its that line that preventing the function from going through and hence it just refreshes the page when i hit on submit

Comment: there is a bracket missing. Replace the error-line with this: `$form.append($('<input type="text" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));`

Comment: thanks for that. were almost there, and i greatly appreciate your work and patience. Please have a look at an image i included under the update section of my initial post

Comment: just to clarify a bit  
Ok allow me to clarify. this line $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false); disables the button after click, but it should only disable the button after a succesfully click, in other words after this function been executed function handleCall

Comment: ok... if you move this line, `$('#[put the input id here]').prop('disabled', true);` to the anonymous success function in the `phpCall()`, the button will only disabled when the request was successful. I edited my code above.

Comment: Hi I have credited you for your work which has been nothing short but incredible. You have indeed answer my question. Just two minor things how would i be able to post the value of this input  $form.append($('<input type="text" name="stripeToken" />').val(token)); that is generated so that i can retrieve it on the php page as such     $course_token = $_POST['stripeToken']; and the php page seems to be run in an alert box for some reason where when it takes user to a new page just the html code of that page is shown in the alert box

Comment: `.val(token)` do not change the value-attribute of the tag. So replacing it with `.attr("value", token);` should solve your first Problem.

Comment: Your second problem sounds like you have no php-interpreter on your server?! :D

Comment: hi i have included the php code under my initial post. it seems to just head down to the header and ignore everything above. In addition it prints out the relocation page in the form of html

Comment: i also added a picture to really make it explicit

Comment: NOTE: Not the browser retrieves the response, but the ajax success-method. if you want to e.g. redirect the user to an other page (that is what the browser do automatically for you), you have to do it manually.

Comment: I am an php-amateur. What exactly should the php-script do? Redirect the user to an other page?

Comment: i am not so preoccupied with the php as I can manuver it, my main question is that the result is shown an alert box. in particular this line             alert(response);
 in the phpcall fuction. where i wouldnt want to be executed under an alert

Comment: You want to render this html as a new page?!

Comment: yes the php code is run seperatetly all i needed was to retreive the token so i could store it as a variable

Comment: but i could only get the token variable once the function has been succesfully executed

Comment: normally `header("Location: ...");` should work. try to replace it with `header("Location: https://www.google.de/);` if this still don't work, you should ask a new question....

Answer (score 1):

The request is asynchronous!

1. Create a function that executes your script and calls the `phpCall()` at the end.
2. Make your html formular call the new method.

-> The request should be started when the script was done.

EDIT: The new function could look like this:

```
// You don't need jQuery

function onSubmit() {
    var $form = $('#'+id_from_form);

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('input').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    phpCall();
}
```

Call method on the submitButton and change his type from submit to button:

```
<input type="button" onClick="onSubmit()" value="Submit" name="submit" />
```

(You can remove the action and method attribute from the form tag)

```
<form id="my-form">
    <!-- stuff -->
    <!-- put the input tag here -->
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for you're edit. I have 2 concerns. 1 ) the php function seems to run regardless wheter this line has been executed or not         $form.append($('<input type="text" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
 when it should only run after this line since i need to be able to grab the token

Comment: try: `$form.append($('<input type="text" name="stripeToken" />').val(token).each(phpCall));` This should call the `phpCall()` once, after setting the value.

Comment: thanks, we also further elaborate that this form.append can only be run once until the user lands on that page again? Because what is happening now is once the button has been clicked it just runs the function automaticly when ever the page refreshes without even clicking the button. You should be able to hit the submit button multiple times since it needs to validate if for instance your credit card format is correct, and if everything is fine it goes into the else statement, where you have the form.append, so really have that form.append only run once until you hit submit again

Comment: define a variable in the scope of the if-statement with initial value `false` (`var appendedStripeToken = false;`). create a new function: `function handleCall() { appendedStripeToken = true; if (appendedStripeToken) phpCall(); }`. Now replace `.each(phpCall)` with `.each(handleCall)`. Was that, what you meant?

Comment: sry.... i made a mistake. here is the new handleCall(): `function handleCall() { if (!appendedStripeToken) { appendedStripeToken = true; phpCall(); } } `

Comment: thanks for your continuous suggestion. It seems i may have not properly apply your suggestion, i have included an update under the update section of my initial post

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the function `phpCall()` but you are not calling it anywhere within your script. Simply call the function or remove function declaration so that function internals run procedurally.

Comment: thanks for your response. My questions are as follow, where whithin my script i would declare it and how, and the other question is would i be able to retrieve the stripeToken as such in the php page? $token = isset($_POST['stripeToken']) ? $_POST['stripeToken']: null;